# using wsprintf with malloc

Tags: c++, c, string, winapi

Is there any mistake to write a code such:

```
char* sp=(char*)malloc(128);
int x=22;

wsprintf(sp,"%d",x);
cout<<sp;
```

I am asking specially about security mistakes?

Comment: What's the advantage over `cout << x`?

Comment: C has no such function `wsprintf`...? Are you thinking of `swprintf`? But the signature does not match it either. By the way, why is this question tagged both C and C++?

Comment: Microsoft API has a method wsprintf but their documentation says it is deprecated. UNIX manpages seems to think wsprintf works the same as swprintf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of "potential" issues here, non of them is actually infinging anything but you may find things not behaving as you expect.

First: wsprintf, as a Win32 API ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ) is prototyped as:

```
int __cdecl wsprintf(
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpOut,
  _In_   LPCTSTR lpFmt,
  _In_    ...
);
```

where `LPTSTR` is defined as `char*` or `wchar_t*` depending on the definition or not of the `UNICODE` symbol (check your propject settings and / or build commands)

Now, in case you are on an ANSI build (no UNICODE) all types are coherent, but there is no check about wsprintf writing more than the 128 char you allocated. If you just write a decimal integer it will have no problem, but if you (of somebody else after you) modify later the "message" and no checks are made, some surprises may arise (like `wsprintf(sp,"This is the number I've been told I was supposed to be expected to be: %d",x);` will this still fits the 128 chars?!? )

In case you are on a UNICODE build, you allocate 128 char, and write a double-byte string on it. The number 22 will be written as `\x32\x00\x32\x00\x00\x00` (3200 is the little-endian coding for 0x0032 that is the wchar_t correponding to the UNICODE 50 that stands for '2').
If you give that sequence to cout (that is char based, not wchar_t based) will see the first \x00 as a string terminator and will output ... just '2'.

To be coherent, you shold either:

- use all `char` based types and function (OK malloc and cout, but `wsprintfA` instead of `wsprintf`)
- use all `wchar_t` based types and function (malloc(128*sizeof(wchar_t)), wchar_t* and `wsprintfW`)
- use all `TCHAR` based types (malloc(128*sizeof(TCHAR)), TCHAR* and wsprintf, but define `tcout` as `cout` or `wcout` depending on UNICODE).

Comment: Correct until the last statement. There is no tcout in C.

Comment: @CashCow: please read carefully: I said "define tcout". Does an imperative verb means something to you?

Comment: @CashCow: please understand that this is an answer to a question that is tagged both C and C++, in which the OP himself used cout. Your nitpicking makes no sense, in this context.

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't write code in a mix of the worst features of C and C++. Either write all in one language, or pick the best features of each.

Comment: @CashCow: Now you are trolling. What I should do depends on what the OP did. Stop yelling and read VERY CAREFULLY both the question and the answer. How can I answer a question about C++ interoperability with Win32 C API without mixing C and C++??

Comment: Because we want to train the OP not to write poor code or use deprecated functions, particularly ones with such a bad name like wsprintf which anyone would intuitively think is swprintf.

Comment: And good reasons for using C++ is because it comes with a string class and a vector class and smart pointers and destructors to make memory management easier, as well as that it comes with templates and polymorphism. You don't use C++ simply for cout which is reasonably well handled already in the C language with printf.

Comment: That's religion, not science. And I'm not interested in becoming whatever kind of priest. Fell free open yourself your "mission". I'll not suport it..

Answer (score 1):

There is no security mistake because it is never the case that an int converted to a C string will exceed the size you've allocated.

However this style of programming has the *potential* for security issues. And history has shown that this kind of code has caused real security issues time and time again. So maybe you should be learning a better style of coding?

Comment: What ypu mean by `potential for security issues` can you give an example.

Comment: what do you mean by security issues?

Comment: Most likely that sizes may change for types, and also that sprintf doesn't limit number of bytes written like snprintf. My guess.

Answer (score 0):

Ok given that you have stated you are using winapi, read this from their [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/):

> Note  Do not use. Consider using one of the following functions
>   instead: StringCbPrintf, StringCbPrintfEx, StringCchPrintf, or
>   StringCchPrintfEx. See Security Considerations.

Therefore do not use. I would ignore however what they tell you to do instead and either:

1. Write in C, and a function from the C standard library (sprintf, snprintf etc). In that case you cannot use cout.
2. Write in C++. Use std::string and there is even a new to_string, as well as boost::format and ostringstream to help you build formatted string. You can still use C standard library functions there if you want to as well when it really suits your purpose better, but leave the allocation stuff to the library.

Comment: Where's the two-byte character string? w in this context doesn't mean wide.

Comment: I am using wsprintf NOT swprintf !

Comment: I *think* wsprintf follows TCHAR size, so if you compile as unicode, then you WILL have a problem. If you don't plan to build as unicode, use `sprintf` instead.

Comment: See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.basetechref%2Fdoc%2Fbasetrf1%2Fprintf.htm

swprintf is slightly different in that you put in a maximum size.

Comment: @Roddy no it doesn't , there is a tstring version _tsprintf or whatever Microsoft call it.

Comment: @CashCow : Params are of type LPTSTR LPCTSTR. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374131(v=vs.85).aspx and here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Cashcow - question is tagged WINAPI, btw... Good catch with the unix variant, though!

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh969198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists some concerns over the use of `wsprintf`. They don't appear to apply to your example but they do give some alternatives that you might want to explore.